# Is it possible to add a command like 'rs' to nodemon?

Tags: node.js, express, command-line-interface, nodemon

I'm using nodemon to develope an express application, and I was wondering if it is possible to add a custom command (like 'rs' which restarts the application [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dBAU.png)) to the cli?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `nodemon` to [pass stdin to your application](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md#nodemon-doesnt-work-with-my-repl) and have your application listen for commands.

If you want `rs` to still work, though, you'd have to do something extra like:

- Using `nodemon` as a module, monitoring your application's `stdout` for a certain signal/command to make `nodemon` restart.
- Configure `nodemon` to restart whenever the file `./restart` changes, then simply have your application write to this file when it wants to restart.

No real graceful solution as far as I know.